# Phonegap iOS Keyboard event without focus

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, jquery-events

I'm currently developing a simple iOS/Android app with phonegap. To improve the user experience the app works with a lot of shortcuts. (Physical keyboard required). To handle shortcut events I'm using  the the onkeypress event together with JQuery, which works very well on Android. Unfortunately no event is fired on IOS. If I set the focus to an input element the onkeypress listener works as expected.

My questions:
How can I detect key events on iOS without setting the focus to an input element?
Are there any plugins or workaround to solve this issue?

Update

I've tried a normal input field and everything works as expected. If I change the input to a hidden one the code does not work anymore.

Comment: can you please clarify "Physical Keyboard required", which key are you trying to trigger ?

Comment: i.e $ or ! or any other kind of letter like g , a , b, c, d ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for my problem:

I ve added a div containing an input field this div has a z-index of -10 so it does not appear

the hidden field always owns the focus until an other input field is selected. The new selected input field gets a blur function to bring the focus back to the hidden field.

The hidden field

```
<div style="position:absolute;width:1px;heigth:1px;overflow:hidden">
        <input type="text" id="hiddencode" style="position:absolute;left:10px;top:10px;z-index:-1"/>
</div>
```

The js part

```
var blurFunction = function(e) {


     setTimeout(function(){
          console.log(document.activeElement); // This is the element that has focus
          if($(document.activeElement).is("input") || (document.activeElement).is("select")) {

             $(document.activeElement).blur(blurFunction);
         }
         else {
             $('#hiddencode').focus();
         }
         $('#hiddencode').val("");
     });
};
$('#hiddencode').focus();
```